# Do different constructions of real numbers provide a model for the axiomatic system of the real numbers?

Tags: category-theory, model-theory

I do not know much about mathematical logic but my understanding is that once an axiomatic system has a model, it is consistent. If this is the case what should be the characteristics of the model?

More specifically, what makes Dedekind cuts a suitable model for real numbers, from which we can conclude the consistency of the axiomatic system of real numbers?

Comment: That depends on your axioms. Essentially, you just verify all of them. This is often done in the first few weeks of calculus courses.

Comment: Thanks but why verification of axioms by cuts of rational numbers is sufficient?

Comment: How else do you plan on checking that something is a model of your axioms?

Comment: Yes that is my question what determines something is a model of your axiom and something is not.

Comment: You check to see if the axiom holds or not...

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now. So the model does not need to have any physical interpretation, it could be anything as long as it verifies the axioms. I mean we can interpret the undefined terms of the axiomatic systems in terms of anything.

Comment: Physical interpretation has absolutely no room in mathematics. At best it can be used as a guiding intuition, but even that is far fetched in mathematical logic and foundations of mathematics.